# How is it that I can strupr work but strcpy does not

Tags: c, string, pointers

Here is my code.

```
int main()
{
struct emp
{
    char *n;
    int age;
};
struct emp e1 = {"Dravid", 23};
struct emp e2 = e1;
strupr(e2.n);
printf("%s\n", e1.n);
return 0;
}
```

Question 1: The answer as per the website is 'DRAVID' that is upper case. Howcome, are e2 and e1 same? i.e. if I do, e2.age++ then will this change be reflected in e1 too?

Question 2: If I  change the strupr to strcpy I get seg fault? Why? i.e. If i change it to `strcpy(e2.n,"hoho");`.

Comment: If you change strupr to strcpy you should get a compile error, because strcpy expects 2 arguments, not 1.

Comment: Also, calling `strupr()` is UB as well, it also tries to modify the string literal in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you construct your two `emp`s, this is what you have in memory:

```
e1.age  = 23
e1.name = 0x12345678 (Which is a pointer in memory to "Dravid")
e2.age  = 23
e2.name = 0x12345678 (Which is a pointer in memory to "Dravid")
```

Now notes, on what you're trying to do.

1. Calling `strupr(e1.name)` is undefined behavior, because you're not allowed to modify string literals.
2. Calling `strcpy(e1.name, e2.name)` is also undefined behavior, because strcpy requires that the two pointers passed to it refer to different pieces of memory. Also, its UB because you can't modify string literals.
3. Calling `strcpy(e1.name, "hiho")` is also undefined behavior, because you can't modify string literals.

Comment: It is about `strcpy(e2.n,"hoho")`, not `strcpy(e1.name, e2.name)`.

Comment: @glglgl: Thanks, that edit was apparently after I started responding.

Comment: @sharth but the website says that with strupr i will get DRAVID, how come? If that is also not defined behaviour? I am modifying the string there too?

Comment: I can't comment on the contents of a website I don't know of. What I can say is that the code you have shown us is broken for the above reasons.

Comment: @sharth so as per you, if i  use strupr, it is seg fault right?

Comment: @Kraken: It's undefined behavior. A common side-effect of undefined behavior is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @sharth The OP stated the language is C.  Unless the `const` specifier is used, strings are mutable in C and can be modified at will. (In truth, there is no such thing as a C 'string', only character arrays terminated by a null). A segmentation fault may occur if the allocated memory space is overrun by a copy operation.

Comment: @PeterGluck: 2011 C Standard. Section 6.4.5. Paragraph 7. __"It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined."__ This means that an implementation is allowed to store the data in Read Only memory, and that if a piece of code references the string literal "Foo" twice, both of those can refer to the same memory. [PDF of the C-2011 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: @PeterGluck, it is undefined behavior as it is up to the compiler vendor as to how to put literal strings.  for some devices the literal strings may be put into a read only memory for instance.  C is notoriously loose with the rules giving you lots of flexibility as well as lots of rope to hang yourself with.  In some cases the compiler may aggregate strings so that the same text in multiple places points to the same address.

Answer (score 1):

1) Assigning a structure does a memberwise copy.  Since `n` is a pointer, the pointer address is copied so it points to the same string.

2) `strcpy` requires two arguments.  Remember that `e2.n` is a pointer.  You must allocate sufficient space to that pointer to hold the contents of the new string when calling `strcpy`.  You are better off with `strncpy()`:

```
int maxlen = 20;
e2.n = malloc(maxlen);
strncpy(e2.n, "Any length string here", maxlen - 1) /* only copies 19 bytes + terminating null */
```

Comment: Editted. Passing two arguments only.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a struct to another you copy all the values in the struct. For age you just copy the value, so you can change it and they will differ.

For n you are copying the address of the string so when you change one of the strings you also change the other.

And, as H2CO3 pointed out, you can't modify string literals which is what you attempt to do when using strcpy.

Comment: And because you can't change string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. The char * n stores the address, which is copied, so if you change the value at the both will be reflected.

Q2. strcpy() needs 2 parameters, can you show what did you code.

Comment: this is more of a comment/discussion than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

C, unlike Java, uses different memory areas for different variables.  So when you assign one struct to another, it does what is basically a shallow copy of one area to another.  By shallow copy what I mean is that any pointers are not followed through to make clones of those so any pointers will point to the same place.  It is just a copy of one memory area to another.

To say `struct emp e2 = e1;` is the same thing as to say `memcpy (&e2, &e1, sizeof(struct emp));`

This in turn means that if you assign a struct to another struct variable and then modify the data in the other struct variable, the first struct variable is not modified.

So in C each variable is a different memory location where as with Java and some other languages you are working with variable references and the variable names are just containers for the variable reference (except for built in primitives like int).

You have a bit of a possible problem with your code in that you are using a constant string.  It is not good to modify a constant string as you are doing with strupr() because you do not know how the memory is allocated or where it is allocated.  So with doing a strupr() you are basically getting lucky.

See this about [difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).

Answer (score -1):

They should not be the same after the call to strupr (but it's not safe or proper to modify a string literal anyway). And no, a change to `e2` will not be reflected in `e1` because the assignment will copy the object by value.

As for changing the strupr call to strcpy, strcpy takes two arguments, so just changing it will cause a compilation error. If you add `e1.n` as the second argument, it will crash because `e2.n` hasn't been initialized to point to any memory.

Comment: "They should not be the same after the call to strupr" - well, they should, since they point to the same (changed) memory location.

Comment: please remove your answer then.